# URL scheme to open Gmail native app from Chrome on Android

Tags: url, deep-linking, url-scheme

I'm trying to implement a feature over on Android, basically, on the web, you can use `googlegmail:///co?to=email` to open a compose view on the native Gmail app.

`googlegmail:///` doesn't seem to work on Android and I'm really unsure if this type of functionality is possible on Android. Even if it exists for some other app, it would be great to get a working example on Android! Any clarity would be appreciated.